# How to prove that the Church encoding, forall r. (F r -> r) -> r, gives an initial algebra of the functor F?

Tags: functional-programming, type-theory, recursion-schemes, church-encoding, fixpoint-combinators

The well-known Church encoding of natural numbers can be generalized to use an arbitrary functor `F`. The result is the type, call it `C`, defined by

```
  data C = Cfix { run :: forall r. (F r -> r) -> r }
```

Here and below, for simplicity, we will assume that `F` is a fixed, already defined functor.

It is widely known and stated that the type `C` is a fixpoint of the functor `F`, and also that `C` is an initial `F`-algebra. For example, if the functor `F a` is defined by

```
 data F a b = Empty | Cons a b
```

then a fixpoint of `F a` is `[a]` (the list of values of type `a`). Also, `[a]` is the initial algebra. The Church encoding of lists is well known. But I could not find a rigorous proof of either of these statements (`C` is a fixpoint, and `C` is the initial algebra).

The question is, how to prove rigorously one of the two statements:

1. The type `C` is a fixpoint of the type isomorphism `F C ≅ C`. In other words, we need to prove that there exist two functions, `fix :: F C -> C` and `unfix :: C -> F C` such that `fix . unfix = id` and `unfix . fix = id`.
2. The type `C` is the initial algebra of the functor `F`; that is, the initial object in the category of `F`-algebras. In other words, for any type `A` such that a function `p :: F A -> A` is given (that is, `A` is an `F`-algebra), we can find a unique function `q :: C -> A` which is an F-algebra morphism. This means, `q` must be such that the law `q . fix = p . fmap q` holds. We need to prove that, given `A` and `p`, such `q` exists and is unique.

These two statements are not equivalent; but proving (2) implies (1). (Lambek's theorem says that an initial algebra is an isomorphism.)

The code of the functions `fix` and `unfix` can be written relatively easily:

```
 fix :: F C -> C
 fix fc  = Cfix (forall r. \g -> g . fmap (\h -> h g) fc )
 unfix :: C -> F C
 unfix c = (run c) (fmap fix)
```

Given a function `p :: F A -> A`, the code of the function `q` is written as

```
 q :: C -> A
 q c = (run c) p
```

However, it seems difficult to prove directly that the functions `fix`, `unfix`, `q` satisfy the required properties. I was not able to find a complete proof.

Is it easier to prove that `C` is an initial algebra, i.e., that `q` is unique, than to prove that `fix . unfix = id`?

In the rest of this question, I will show some steps that I was able to make towards the proof that `fix . unfix = id`.

It is not possible to prove either (1) or (2) simply by using the given code of the functions. We need additional assumptions. Similarly to the Yoneda identity,

```
 forall r. (A -> r) -> F r   ≅   F A   ,
```

we need to assume that the functions' code is fully parametric (no side effects, no specially chosen values or fixed types) so that the parametricity theorem can be applied. So, we need to assume that the type `C` contains only functions of type `forall r. (F r -> r) -> r` that satisfy the appropriate naturality law.

The parametricity theorem gives the following naturality law for this type signature: for any types `A` and `B`, and for any functions `p :: F B -> A` and `f :: A -> B`, the function `c :: forall r. (F r -> r) -> r` must satisfy the equation

```
  c (f . p) = f . c (p . fmap f)
```

Using this naturality law with appropriately chosen `p` and `f`, one can show that the composition `fix . unfix` is a certain function of type `C -> C` that must be equal to `\c -> (run c) fix`.

However, further progress in the proof does not seem to be possible; it is not clear why this function must be equal to `id`.

Let us temporarily define the function `m`:

```
 m :: (F C -> C) -> C -> C
 m t c = (run c) t
```

Then the result I have is written as

```
fix . unfix  = m fix
```

One can also show that `unfix . fix = fmap (m fix)`.

It remains to prove that `m fix = id`. Once that is proved, we will have proved that `F C ≅ C`.

The same naturality law of `c` with different choice of `p` and `f` gives the strange identity

```
 m fix . m (m fix . fix) = m (m fix . fix)
```

But I do not know how to derive from this identity that `m fix = id`.

Comment: You may get better responses on https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Metropolis, maybe [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) could be an even better match.

Comment: I asked on cs and cstheory.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/131901/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47819/5038, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64666513/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @Metropolis, may I make a request?  In the future, if you suggest another site, might you be willing to let the poster know that they should avoid cross-posting?  You could mention that they can delete the post here before posting elsewhere.  I'm hoping that will provide a better experience for all (e.g., so the poster doesn't feel blindsided by this rule).  Thank you for listening.

Comment: @Enrico, may I make the same request to you as well?  Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131901/how-to-prove-that-the-church-encoding-forall-r-f-r-r-r-gives-an-initi  but community rules do not allow cross-posting.

Comment: The question has been answered here, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131901/how-to-prove-that-the-church-encoding-forall-r-f-r-r-r-gives-an-initi

Comment: @D.W., yes, sure.